# Are there any rear derailleurs compatible with Shimano Tourney RD TX 80

Tags: derailleur, compatibility, tourney

I need a new rear derailleur for my Claud Butler Urban 200.

I have looked at the old one and can see it is a Shimano Tourney RD TX 80 -7.

I have found these quite hard to get and I am wondering if there are any other models that would be compatible for my bike?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with the existing one that means you need to replace it?  Did it get bent or worn out ?

Comment: @Criggie Would that information change the answer? Are you angling towards a possible "If it's X that's wrong, you don't need to replace it because you can fix it by doing Y"-type answer?

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes - hence its a comment.  Could be replacement of rear mech won't help if its sticky inner cables or maladjustment, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a 7 Speed derailleur? Shimano RD-TX35 7spd should work it is the current derailleur used on the bike as it is specd. [HERE](https://www.evanscycles.com/claud-butler-urban-200-2017-hybrid-bike-EV294635)
But I would also go to your LBS and have them see, they might have a better ability to locate the same one you were using.

Comment: Tourney TX55 should also be compatible. The difference between the 35 and 55 seems to be a sort of friction reducing wheel for the shift cable

Comment: Thank you John, TX35 might be worth a try.
I just noticed a typo in my question, I meant to say the 
Claud Butler urban 100. 
Any thoughts on that.
Thanks again

Comment: Well that bike uses a 6 spd rear derailleur, so really any 6 speed the attaches to the frame the same way will work. I still recommend you go to a bike shop, they should have one on hand for pretty cheap. plus installation of a derailleur is more than just attaching it to the frame. If you aren't confident on adjusting limit screws. have them do it. Also might need new cables, and might need to adjust chain length or replace chain.

Comment: Thank you  Argenti Apparatus and John Burgess.  Yes the new Urban 100 is a six speed, but mine is an older one and is a 7 speed (21 gears )
Ok, thank you for the good advice re the bike shop.  
All the best